# Erro ao validar data com Carbon?

Tags: laravel-5

Estou fazendo um teste e passando uma data inválida para um método do Carbon.

```
$data = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '06/17/2010');
```

Como podem observar, o método cria a partir do padrão `d/m/y` (***padrão brasileiro***), sendo assim a data informada como argumento está inválida, pois o valor do mês é maior que 12.

Imaginei que alguma mensagem erro iria aparecer, mas não aparece nada, se eu tentar ver o que tem na variável `$data`, aparece uma data formatada quando é uma data válida, funciona normalmente.

O resultado ao executar a linha de código acima é:

```
2011-05-06 16:57:13.0 America/Sao_Paulo (-03:00)
```

Por que esse comportamento do Carbon?

Comment: Creio que o carbon não serve para poder validar datas, você não achar melhor você tratar isso antes de convert o dado? Você pode usar o `Validator` do próprio Laravel para te ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Quando utiliza esse comando precisa ser verificado se houve algum erro, com o método `getLastErrors()` que por essa data informada `06/17/2010` tem o seguinte resultado:

```
>>> $data = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '06/17/2010');
=> Carbon\Carbon {#1031
     +"date": "2011-05-06 00:46:30.000000",
     +"timezone_type": 3,
     +"timezone": "America/Sao_Paulo",
   }
>>> \Carbon\Carbon::getLastErrors()
=> [
     "warning_count" => 1,
     "warnings" => [
       10 => "The parsed date was invalid",
     ],
     "error_count" => 0,
     "errors" => [],
   ]
>>>
```

então, além de utilizar o método `createFromFormat`, logo após precisa chamar o método `getLastErrors()` e com o seu `array` de informações verificar `warning_count` e `error_count` se são iguais a zero, se não forem tem problemas na data.

Código exemplo:

```
$data = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '06/17/2010');
$error = Carbon::getLastErrors();
if ($error['error_count'] === 0 && $error['warning_count'] === 0) 
{
    //data válida
}
else
{
    //data inválida
}
```

Vale também lembrar que a classe Carbon herdam os comportamentos da classe [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.datetime.php) que possui o mesmo método [DateTime::createFromFormat](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.createfromformat.php), que explica os problemas e erros encontrados em um data pelo mesmo método [DateTime::getLastErrors()](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.getlasterrors.php).

Se deseja somente verificar se a data é válida pode utilizar a função [date_parse_from_format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php) da seguinte forma:

```
$errors = date_parse_from_format('d/m/Y','06/17/2010')
```

que retorna praticamente as mesmas informações do metodo `getLastErrors()`, exemplo:

```
=> [
     "year" => 2010,
     "month" => 17,
     "day" => 6,
     "hour" => false,
     "minute" => false,
     "second" => false,
     "fraction" => false,
     "warning_count" => 1,
     "warnings" => [
       10 => "The parsed date was invalid",
     ],
     "error_count" => 0,
     "errors" => [],
     "is_localtime" => false,
   ]
```

ou seja, verifique `error_count` e `warning_count` se os dois forem do valor **0** a *data é válida*, se for maior que **0** qualquer uma a *data não é válida*.